# ImageMagick Colorize GIF and Preserve Transparency

Tags: imagemagick

I have a small icon GIF that I would like to change the color. All opaque GIF pixels should be replaced by this new color, but preserve transparency for the gif. Then I need to place that new colored GIF over a background map, all in one command line. Here is what I have, but it's not changing all gif opaque pixels. Attached is the GIF icon. (Edit: I know im only targeting the white here, but just can't figure out how to target ALL opaque pixels in the GIF)

`exec("{$convert} {$map_image} \( {$map_icon} -fill orange -opaque white -geometry +1700+600 \)  -composite  map2.jpg ");`

[image]

Comment: smells like schoolwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use +opaque none to fill all non-transparent colors in ImageMagick. The +opaque means everything "but" that color.

```
convert grid.gif -fill orange +opaque none x.png
```

[image]

Comment: ~ Thank you! Ive been at this for hours. Really appreciate your help!